# Matching Password against local filename

Tags: php, string, authentication

I know this is bad practice.  It's temporary until I get these passwords into an AD environment.  The point is, I am trying to get the password matching to work and it appears that I'm missing something.

Basically, I have a `.secrets` file that holds the passwords in the following format:

```
user1:pass1
user2:pass2
etc, etc
```

Here is the entire PHP file:

```
<?php

//If Submit Button Is Clicked Do the Following
if ($_POST['submit']){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $secret_word = $_POST['secret_word'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $fh = fopen('.secrets','r');
  $result = explode(":",$fh);
  for($i=0; $i< count($result); $i++){
    if($result[$i] === $username && $result[$i+1] === $secret_word) {
      echo "Matched";
      break;
    } else {
        echo "Secret Word Incorrect - Please try again";
        break;
    }
  }
  fclose($fh);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
<p>User:</p>
<input name="username" required="required" type="text" id="username" />
<p>Password:</p>
<input name="password" required="required" type="password" id="password" />
<p>Confirm Password:</p>
<input name="password_confirm" required="required" type="password" id="password_confirm" oninput="check(this)" />
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    function check(input) {
        if (input.value != document.getElementById('password').value) {
            input.setCustomValidity('Password Must be Matching.');
        } else {
            // input is valid -- reset the error message
            input.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    }
</script>
<p>Secret Word:</p>
<input name="secret_word" type="password" required="required" id="secret_word" />
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

The only part not working is the matching and the fact that it doesn't say "Matched" or "Does not match".  I feel like I'm so close to getting this, but I've been trying to get this working for the past 30 minutes.  **By the way, I'm trying to match the username and the "secret_word", not the password field, by the way.**

Output of `print_r`:

```
Array
(
    [username] => user1
    [password] => asdf
    [password_confirm] => asdf
    [secret_word] => pass1
    [submit] => Submit
)
```

Comment: What's the result of `print_r($result)`?

Comment: @hungrykoala - Updated question with results.

Comment: I meant this `$result = explode(":",$fh);`

Comment: @hungrykoala I'd assume it would throw a `notice` or return nothing because we were trying to `explode` on a file handle and not the file's contents. You'd need to do `$result = explode(":", fread($fh, filesize(".secrets")));`

Comment: @csb it could have but I can't say for sure since there was no error/notice posted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you opened the file for reading but did not actually proceed to read the file.

I've chosen to use PHP's [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead to make things less verbose.

The next thing I did was to split the lines (`\n`) first, before splitting on `:`. If we just sent ahead to split on `:`, you would have trailing newlines on some of your data - which you could also `trim()` away. I've just chosen this method because it's clearer.

The updated code looks like this:

```
if ($_POST['submit']){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $secret_word = $_POST['secret_word'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $file = file_get_contents('.secrets');
  $lines = explode("\n", $file);

  $matched = false;

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    list($stored_user, $stored_pass) = explode(":", $lines[$i]);

    if ($stored_user === $username && $stored_pass === $secret_word) {
      $matched = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if ($matched) {
    echo "Matched!";
  } else {
    echo "Secret Word Incorrect - Please try again";
  }
}
```

Comment: this almost works.  It matches the first line, but anything after that it does not match.  So any user:pass after the first one, does not match.

Comment: My mistake. I was too eager to solve the file read issue that I didn't handle the matching condition so well. I've updated the code.

Comment: Wow - made it look easy :) . Thanks again for clearing this up for me.  It's been a good while since I've messed with PHP (it obviously shows).  I'm been heads down in BASH lately, as I'm not a developer by trade.  Thanks again!